# geolocation calculation: calculate points if they are within a radius

Tags: geolocation

ok here is the problem:
I want to show to my users the closest geopoints in his vicinity.

i have arround 55.000 fixed geopoints which could be shown. (I have for all of them long/lat)
dependent on the users location (long/lat) i want to show the closest 20 geopoints.

so of course i could just calculate all 55.000 geopoints and see if there are 20 within a certain radius of the users lang/lat and rank them afterwards but this would be somehow an overhead to calculate always 55tsd geopoints.

is there a posibility to "add" 5-miles/kilometers range to a users long and lat and calculate only the distance for those which are within this radius?

i hope you get what i mean. :) 
Merci

Comment: What data structure are these stored in? are they in a database or just in an array, a flatfile...?

Comment: In any case, you should look into [bounding coordinates](http://janmatuschek.de/LatitudeLongitudeBoundingCoordinates) You can calculate (using some fun math) a long/lat to look between so you only have to rank a subset of your items. I don't have time to write up a full answer, especially without knowing which technologies you're planning to use, but that should get you started

Answer (score 0):

If the calculation of distance between all points take too much time, you could narrow down the possible points just by simple difference between lat/lon (source_lat - target_lat) (source_lon - target_lon) and take only the closest point to final calculation of distance. You could use formula to calculate distance.

```
D = 60* 1.1515 * acos (sin(pi*y/180) * sin(pi*Y/180) +
                   cos(pi*y/180) * cos(pi*Y/180) * cos((z-Z) *pi / 180) 
                     )  * 180 / pi)
```

But the efficiency of calculation depends on used database technology as well.

Comment: Could you provide a more elaborate explanation on what exactly is going on in this formula. What exactly is `60* 1.1515`